# How to set ambient light with EEVEE

Tags: light, lighting, eevee-render-engine

I have a model from an OBJ import and I would like to light it in (using Eevee) in a way that is similar to OpenGL ambient light. The only thing that I found similar is the background color of the scene: if I set it to white, the results are similar to set an white ambient light in OpenGL.
Is it correct and/or there exists some other way to uniformly light all in the scene?

Comment: use a solid color world background

Comment: ok and this is what I was doing (see the question), I was asking if there is a better/more elegant way