# How do I make ambient light in building with sky?

Tags: lighting, world

I'm creating an abandoned factory/warehouse building, and I've run into a lighting problem.  I've searched a lot on Blender SE for a solution, but none [of](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/139083/132727) [the](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/123114/132727) [questions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/97079/132727) I found helped. [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/135291/132727) is very similar to mine, but [the answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/135300/132727) is not helpful at all for me, as in my case I have a very bright, direct light shining directly into the building.

For my world's sky, I'm using *Background* surface with an *Environment Texture* using an image. Here is the node setup for my world:

[image]

[A lower-quality version of DSCF6016.JPG (the sky)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ggd8y.jpg).

Here's a screenshot using *Scene World*, where the sky looks perfect, but there is absolutely no light inside the building, except where the sun hits the floor:

[image]

Turning up the strength for the scene world doesn't really do anything until the strength is extreme (>400), and even then it just turns the floor blue, and does nothing to the walls.

When I uncheck *Scene World* in the *Shading* dropdown, and adjust the settings, the interior lighting looks pretty good, but the sky is dull:

[image]

If I turn up the strength (where the cursor is), the sky looks better, but then the interior is too *bright!*

When I switch from using my image to using a sky texture, the building still isn't light.

Since the building is abandoned, there can't be any artificial light in there. Is there a simple way to get the sky like the first image, and the interior like the second one? I'm still getting used to Blender's fine points, so there may have been something obvious I missed, but I've been trying to solve this problem for hours, and I can't seem to get it right. I'm using Blender 3.0.1 on an Ubuntu 20.04. I can provide more screenshots/information if you need.

Comment: "Scene lights" and "scene world" toggle between _your_ lighting (the lighting you have set up in the scene including lights and HDRI's), and the lighting and HDRI that is built in to blender's Material Preview scene preset. I would advise you to leave both boxes checked (while in rendered preview mode), so as not to confuse your lighting setup with built in lighting presets. Also, are you using Cycles or EEVEE?

Comment: As @ChristopherBennett already asked, are you using _Cycles_ or _Eevee_? For to light up the interior walls you need light bouncing off the floor, but there is no bounce light in _Eevee_. The other thing is, you're using a JPEG for the sky which has a very low dynamic range and therefore not much brightness. To properly light the scene you need an HDRI for the background.

Comment: By the way, if you would take pictures with a real camera inside a dark warehouse (or almost every time you take pictures inside a room only lit by windows), the exposure is usually so high that when the walls are bright enough, the sky would be blown out overly bright and not look as the sky when you would take a picture outside.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett I'm using Evee.

Comment: EEVEE doesn't do "bounced lighting" by default like cycles does - this is why light coming through the roof cracks doesn't light up the (indirectly lit parts of the) room. To do this in EEVEE, you need to use an _Irradiance Volume_. See an answer I posted recently about it here - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/264928/75504

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Yes, that answer worked perfectly! Thank you much! (turns out I've already upvoted it :D) Should this question be closed as a duplicate of that one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the first part of your question is answered by a (somewhat) duplicate question (just using very different words), I will attempt to answer the second part of your Q (although putting two questions in one is technically discouraged here) so as to make it a valid question in it's own right (which is also likely a dupe, I just can't find a link at the moment).

If you want to separate the background (HDRI) image from it's lighting influence, you can use a node setup similar to what is pictured below in the *World* shader. I used black as an easy example, but you can just as easily use different colors, or even a second HDRI. The reverse works as well - if you want the light from the HDRI, but want to replace the image with something else, just reverse the order of the Mix Shader inputs:

[image: LightsNStuff]